# Read a string till spaces

Tags: java

I want to read string till spaces using `BufferedReader`."Hello world" should be read as "Hello" and then "world" and not "Hello world".Is there a function to do it? `BufferedReader.readLine()` reads full line and not the words separately.
Thanx!!

Comment: Use a `Scanner` instead.

Comment: No i want to do with buffered reader.

Comment: Read one character at a time until you hit a space.

Comment: Or split each line after you have read it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `readLine()` and then split the read String with `split(" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.readLine()` with a `BufferedReader`, use a `Scanner`. This way you can use the `.next()` to get the next thing up to whitespace (any whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a BufferedReader, you can use the `int read()` method instead of `String readLine()`. See the BufferedReader [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read())